# Trying to replace text in files throws a error

Tags: c

The point of the script is to take three parameters. Find, replace, prefix. Find being the text to replace, replace being what to replace the text with, and prefix is a special case. If prefix is in the text, you replace the prefix (some text) with prefix+replace. I would like to know why the below code throws a error right after saying opened file. It only seems to throw an error if the text being replaced is repeated like "aaa", "bbb" where "a" is what is being replaced.

```
 Opened file.txt
 *** Error in `./a.out': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00005652fbc55980 ***
```

There's also the occasionally seg fault after printing "Trying to replace for file ...". I'm not fluent in C and GDB on my system resulted in just missing library errors which has nothing to do with this. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

char concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result = calloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1, 1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    printf("Prefix will be replaced with %s.\n", result);
    return result;
}

static int replaceString(char *buf, const char *find, const char *replace, const char *prefix)
{

    int olen, rlen;
    char *s, *d;
    char *tmpbuf;

    if (!buf || !*buf || !find || !*find || !replace)
        return 0;

    tmpbuf = calloc(strlen(buf) + 1, 1);

    if (tmpbuf == NULL)
        return 0;

    olen = strlen(find);
    rlen = strlen(replace);

    s = buf;
    d = tmpbuf;

    while (*s) {
        if (strncmp(s, find, olen) == 0) {
            strcpy(d, replace);
            s += olen;
            d += rlen;
        }
        else
        {
            *d++ = *s++;
        }
    }

    *d = '\0';

   if(strcmp(buf, tmpbuf) == 0)
   {
          free(tmpbuf);
          return 0;
   }
   else
   {
         strcpy(buf, tmpbuf);
         free(tmpbuf);
         printf("%s", buf);
         printf("Replaced!\n");
         return 1;
   }

}

void getAndReplace(char* filename, char* find, char* replace, char* prefix)
{

   long length;
   FILE* f = fopen (filename, "r");
   char* buffer = 0;

   if (f)
   {
      fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
      length = ftell (f);
      fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
      buffer = calloc(length+1, 1); //If i use malloc here, any file other than the first has garbage added to it. Why?
      if (buffer)
      {
        fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
      }
      fclose(f);
   }

   if(buffer)// && strlen(buffer) > 1)
   {
      int result = replaceString(buffer, find, replace, prefix);

      if(result == 0)
      {
         printf("Trying to replace prefix.\n");
         replace = concat(prefix, replace);
         result = replaceString(buffer, prefix, replace, "");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Successfully replaced %s with %s\n", find, replace);
      }

      if(result == 1)
      {
         FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w+");
         if(fp)
         {
             printf("Opened %s\n", filename);
             fprintf(fp, buffer);
             fclose(fp);
             printf("File %s overwritten with changes.\n", filename);
         }
      }
      else
      {
          printf("Nothing to replace for %s\n", filename);
      }
   }
   else
   {
     printf("Empty file.");
   }
   if(buffer)
   {
      free(buffer);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc < 4)
    {
      printf("Not enough arguments given: ./hw3 <find> <replace> <prefix>\n");
      return 1;
    }

    struct dirent *de;

    DIR *dr = opendir(".");

    if (dr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open current directory\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
    {
       if(strlen(de->d_name) > 4 && !strcmp(de->d_name + strlen(de->d_name) - 4, ".txt"))
       {
            printf("Trying to replace for file %s\n", de->d_name);
            getAndReplace(de->d_name, argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
       }
    }

    closedir(dr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `-g -fsanitize=address` to your compiler flags, should help you pinpoint the issue. I didn't bother reading your whole code, but you understand you're copying s1 into result, then immediately overwriting it with s2?

Comment: Did you enable warnings when you compiled this? `char concat()` should be declared as `char *concat()`.

Comment: Depending on the length of `find` and `replace`, you might not have enough memory for `tmpbuf`. Use `strstr` to find the string, calculate the new length after replacement and keep doing that until you've found everything. With new new size, you can allocate the needed amount of bytes for `tmpbuf`. Or you can reallocate on the go.

Comment: the posted code results in the compiler outputting some warnings.  Some of those warnings are quite serious.  One is a security problem.  When compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this signature: `char concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)` states that the returned value will be a single character,  HOWEVER, the actual returned value is a pointer to char  I.E. `char *`

Comment: when a system function returns an error indication, don't hide it from the user.  Instead output to `stderr`, an error message AND the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  This is easily done using `perror()`

Comment: what are you expecting this line: `if(strlen(de->d_name) > 4 && !strcmp(de->d_name + strlen(de->d_name) - 4, ".txt"))` to accomplish?

Comment: regarding: `if(buffer)
   {
      free(buffer);`  the function: `free()`  handles a NULL pointer correctly, so no need to check.

Comment: of this fails: `FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w+");`  then the code just skips the following 'if()` statement and keeps on executing.  I doubt the code should keep on running without (at least) letting the user know that some problem occurred.

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(fp, buffer);`  This is a security violation.  Suggest inserting an appropriate second parameter the contains something like: `"%s"

Comment: regarding: `FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w+");`  why enable reading from the file when the code never reads from it.

Comment: when calling functions like: `ftell()`, `fseek()`, `fread()`, etc, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `else
   {
     printf("Empty file.");`  this call to `printf()` is wrong.  When the code gets here, the call to `calloc()` failed, not the input file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you `concat` function

```
char concat(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

is just a typo and you meant

```
char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

otherwise the function would be returning a pointer as if it were a `char`.

Using valgrind would give more details where exactly you are reading/writing where you are not allowed to and
where you are leaking memory. Without that it's hard to pinpoint the exact
place. One thing I noticed is that depending on the length of `find` and `replace`,
you might not have enough memory for `tmpbuf` which would lead to a buffer
overflow.

I think that the best way to write the `replaceString` is by making it
allocate the memory it needs itself, rather than providing it a buffer to write into.
Because you are getting both `find` and `replace` from the user, you don't know
how large the resulting buffer will need to be. You could calculate it
beforehand, but you don't do that. If you want to pass a pre-allocated buffer to
`replaceString`, I'd pass it as a double pointer, so that `replaceString` can do
`realloc` on it when needed. Or allocate the memory in the function and return a
pointer to the allocated memory.

This would be my version:

```
char *replaceString(const char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace)
{
    if(haystack == NULL || needle == NULL || replace == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *dest = NULL, *tmp;

    size_t needle_len = strlen(needle);
    size_t replace_len = strlen(replace);
    size_t curr_len = 0;

    while(*haystack)
    {
        char *found = strstr(haystack, needle);

        size_t copy_len1 = 0;
        size_t new_size = 0;
        size_t pre_found_len = 0;

        if(found == NULL)
        {
            copy_len1 = strlen(haystack) + 1;
            new_size = curr_len + copy_len1;
        } else {
            pre_found_len = found - haystack;
            copy_len1 = pre_found_len;
            new_size = curr_len + pre_found_len + replace_len + 1;
        }


        tmp = realloc(dest, new_size);
        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            free(dest);
            return NULL;
        }

        dest = tmp;

        strncpy(dest + curr_len, haystack, copy_len1);

        if(found == NULL)
            return dest; // last replacement, copied to the end

        strncpy(dest + curr_len + pre_found_len, replace, replace_len + 1);
        curr_len += pre_found_len + replace_len;

        haystack += pre_found_len + needle_len;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

The idea in this version is similar to yours, but mine reallocates the memory as
it goes. I changed the name of the arguments to have the same name as the
`strstr` function does based on my documentation:

> *man strstr*
>
> ```
> char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
> ```

Because I'm going to update `haystack` to point past the characters copied, I
use this loop:

```
while(*haystack)
{
    ...
}
```

which means it is going to stop when the `'\0'`-terminating byte is reached.

The first thing is to use `strstr` to locate a substring that matches `needle`.
Base on whether a substring is found, I calculate how much bytes I would need to
copy until the substring, and the new size of the buffer. After that I
reallocate the memory for the buffer and copy everything until the substring,
then append the replacement, update the `curr_len` variable and update the
`haystack` pointer to point past the substring.

If the substring is not found, no more replacements are needed. So we have to
copy the string pointed to by `haystack` and return the constructed string. The
new size of the destination is `curr_len + strlen(haystack) + 1` (the `+1`
because I want the `strncpy` function to also copy the `'\0'`-terminating byte).
And it has to copy `strlen(haystack) + 1` bytes. After the first `strncpy`, the
function returns `dest`.

If the substring is found, then we have to copy everything until the substring,
append the replacement and update the current length and the `haystack` pointer.
First I calculate the string until the found substring and save it in
`pre_found_len`. The new size of the destination will be
`curr_len + pre_found_len + replace_len + 1` (the current length + length of
string until substring + the length of the replacement + 1 for the
`'\0'`-terminating byte). Now the first `strncpy` copies only `pre_found_len`
bytes. Then it copies the replacement.

Now you can call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *orig = "Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy?";
    char *text = replaceString(orig, "a", "_A_");
    if(text)
    {
        puts(orig);
        puts(text);
    }

    free(text);
}
```

which will output:

```
Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy?
Is this the re_A_l life? Is this just f_A_nt_A_sy?
```

Now you can use this function in `getAndReplace` to replace the `prefix`:

```
char *getAndReplace(char* filename, char* find, char* replace, char* prefix)
{
    ...

    char *rep1 = replaceString(buffer, find, replace);

    if(rep1 == NULL)
    {
        // error
        free(buffer);
        return NULL;
    }

    char *prefix_rep = malloc(strlen(replace) + strlen(prefix) + 1);
    if(prefix_rep == NULL)
    {
        // error
        free(buffer);
        free(rep1);
        return NULL;
    }

    sprintf(prefix_rep, "%s%s", replace, prefix);

    char *rep2 = replaceString(rep1, prefix, prefix_rep);

    if(rep2 == NULL)
    {
        // error
        free(buffer);
        free(rep1);
        free(prefix_rep);
        return NULL;
    }

    // rep2 has all the replacements
    ...


    // before leaving
    free(buffer);
    free(rep1);
    free(prefix_rep);

    // returning all replacements
    return rep2;
}
```

When using `malloc` & co, don't forget to check if they return `NULL` and don't
forget to free the memory when not needed.